# Bot not setting permissions on overwritePermissions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a mute command on my discord bot that, when given the users name, gives them the role `Muted`. It creates this role, yet the issue I'm running into is that it doesn't change the permissions within the role. My bot has all the necessary permissions to do something like this. Here is the code I'm using:

```
  let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if(!tomute) return message.reply("Usage: !mute <@user>");
  if(tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Can't mute them!");
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "Muted");
  if(!muterole){
    try{
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Muted",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions:[]
      })
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
          ATTACH_FILES: false,
          SPEAK: false
        });
      });
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
  await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));
  message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted`);

  tomute.addRole(muterole.id).then(() => {
  message.delete()
  tomute.send(`You have been muted in ${message.guild.name}.`)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your forEach into a for loop.

Try using the following code:

```
let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if(!tomute) return message.reply("Usage: !mute <@user>");
  if(tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply("Can't mute them!");
  let muterole = message.guild.roles.find(`name`, "Muted");
  if(!muterole){
    try{
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: "Muted",
        color: "#000000",
        permissions:[]
      })
      for (let i = 0; i < msg.guild.channels.array().length; i++) {
        await msg.guild.channels.array()[i].overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
          ATTACH_FILES: false,
          SPEAK: false
        });
      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e.stack);
    }
  }
  await(tomute.addRole(muterole.id));
  message.reply(`<@${tomute.id}> has been muted`);

  tomute.addRole(muterole.id).then(() => {
  message.delete()
  tomute.send(`You have been muted in ${message.guild.name}.`)
  })
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized that both of our codes should work fine. I'm an idiot.